# Separate sections with a line and automatic numbering

Tags: chapters

**I currently separate parts of a book chapter with a line and a small decoration, like this:**

[image]

**But instead of the decoration, I would like to change the decoration to a number, like this:**

[image]

I have tried using commands such as `\thechapter` and `\thesection`, but they don't make sense here, nor do they automatically number when used like that. Worst case, I can just manually number everything as I have done in the MWE, but I would certainly prefer automatic numbering.

And I would like the sections to start with "2", since the first section won't be numbered.

MWE:

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{pifont,fourier-orns}

    \newcommand\crulefill[1][1ex]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule depth \dimexpr-#1+0.4pt height #1\hfill\kern0pt}
    \newcommand\ornline[2][1ex]{\trivlist\item\crulefill[#1]#2\crulefill[#1]\endtrivlist}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \ornline[0.6ex]{\decoone}
    \bigskip    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \ornline[0.6ex]{2}
    \bigskip    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \ornline[0.6ex]{3}
    \bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \ornline[0.6ex]{4}
    \bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \ornline[0.6ex]{5}
    \bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution defining a `\sectionrule` command to call the rule, which is automatically numbered each time by the `sectionrule` counter. The line

```
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\setcounter{sectionrule}{1}}{}{}
```

is meant to reset the `sectionrule` counter at the beginning of a new chapter.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pifont,fourier-orns}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\crulefill[1][1ex]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule depth \dimexpr-#1+0.4pt height #1\hfill\kern0pt}
\newcommand\ornline[2][1ex]{\trivlist\item\crulefill[#1]#2\crulefill[#1]\endtrivlist}
\newcounter{sectionrule}
\setcounter{sectionrule}{1}
\newcommand{\sectionrule}{%
    \refstepcounter{sectionrule}
    \ornline[0.6ex]{\thesectionrule}
    \bigskip
}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\setcounter{sectionrule}{1}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \sectionrule    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \sectionrule

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \sectionrule

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \sectionrule

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\chapter{A second test chapter}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \sectionrule

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    \sectionrule

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of the first chapter:
[image]